# C++ very small floating point number, preciscion

Tags: c++, boost, precision, gmp, long-double

I am dealing with a code which uses very small numbers of order 10^-15 to 10^-25. I tried using `double` and `long double` but i get a wrong answer as either `0.000000000000000000001` is rounded off to `0` or a number like `0.00000000000000002` is represented as `0.00000000000000001999999999999`.

Since even a small fraction of 1/1000000 makes a huge difference in my final answers, is there an appropriate fix?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double  sum, a, b, c,d;
    a=1;
    b=1*pow(10,-15);
    c=2*pow(10,-14);
    d=3*pow(10,-14);
    sum=a+b+c+d;
    cout<<fixed;
    cout<<setprecision(30);
    cout<<" a   : "<<a<<endl<<" b   : "<<b<<endl<<" c   : "<<c<<endl
        <<" d   : "<<d<<endl; 
    cout<<" sum : "<<sum<<endl<<endl;
    a=a/sum;
    b=b/sum;
    c=c/sum;
    d=d/sum;
    sum=a+b+c+d;
    cout<<" a   : "<<a<<endl<<" b   : "<<b<<endl<<" c   : "<<c<<endl
        <<" d   : "<<d<<endl; 
    cout<<" sum2: "<<sum<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output should be:

```
a   : 1.000000000000000000000000000000
b   : 0.000000000000001000000000000000
c   : 0.000000000000020000000000000000
d   : 0.000000000000030000000000000000
sum : 1.000000000000051000000000000000

a   : 1.000000000000000000000000000000
b   : 0.000000000000001000000000000000
c   : 0.000000000000020000000000000000
d   : 0.000000000000030000000000000000
sum1: 1.000000000000051000000000000000
```

But, the output I get is:

```
a   : 1.000000000000000000000000000000
b   : 0.000000000000001000000000000000
c   : 0.000000000000020000000000000000
d   : 0.000000000000029999999999999998
sum : 1.000000000000051100000000000000

a   : 0.999999999999998787999878998887
b   : 0.000000000000000999999997897899
c   : 0.000000000000019999999999999458
d   : 0.000000000000029999999999996589
sum1: 0.999999999999989000000000000000
```

I tried `double`, `long double` and even `boost_dec_float`, but the output I get are similar.

Comment: Make a struct that is your own representation of the number; with a short for the exponential, and a double for the rest;
Or maybe change the units so that you're not working with such small numbers?

Comment: I would argue this is not a duplicate. The OP knows exactly what is happening, and is asking for a solution to increase precision.

Comment: So your problem is that `3*pow(10,-14)` is being displayed as 0.000000000000029999999999999998 rather than 0.000000000000030000000000000000.  That is pretty much on the limits of the precision of double.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Using IEEE double and then expecting `cout<<setprecision(30);` to deliver 30 digits of precision? I don't exactly call that "know what is happening".

Comment: Dear OP, before complaining, calculate the difference in percentage. I'm not sure you're aware how precise these results are. Could this be an http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, this happens because the numbers cannot be accurately represented in binary, and are rounded to a certain degree.

Now, since you tagged this with `boost` tag, boost has [boost.multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/using_arbitrary_precision_floating_point_types.html) that does exactly what you want. It offers `cpp_dec_float_50` data type which ensures exact computation up to 50 decimal digits. It is used as any other type:

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 value_type;

value_type v1 = 1;
value_type v2 = 3;

value_type v3 = v1 / v2;
```

According to boost doc, this is guaranteed to output only the precise bits:

```
cpp_dec_float_50 seventh = cpp_dec_float_50(1) / 7;
cpp_dec_float_50 circumference = boost::math::constants::pi<cpp_dec_float_50>() * 2 * seventh;
std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_50>::digits10);
std::cout << circumference << std::endl;
```

Comment: Depending on the exact goal, rationals could also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are writing:

```
long double  sum, a, b, c,d;
a=1;
b=1*pow(10,-15);
c=2*pow(10,-14);
d=3*pow(10,-14);
```

The trouble is that the `pow` will be the *double* version of pow - not the long double version.  You need to force one of the arguments to long double:

```
long double  sum, a, b, c,d;
a=1;
b=1*pow(10.0L,-15);
c=2*pow(10.0L,-14);
d=3*pow(10.0L,-14);
```

Comment: This can buy 5-6 additional decimal digits of precision on Intel hardware.